# How to output two lists match to each other into a txt file

Tags: python, list, file

I have two lists here:

```
a=["rate","date","population"]
b=[4,2/3/2021,1523]
```

and I need to ouput these two lists into a txt file like this:

```
rate    date    population
4    2/3/2021    1523
```

the blank space between two words is a tab and I tried to use code like

```
with open("data.txt","w") as outfile:
zipped = zip(a, b)
set1=[]
for i, r in zipped:
    set1.append(i)
    set1.append(r)
 outfile.write(str(set1))
```

but it doesn't work and I don't know how to put the tab space choice into it. Need some helps! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to add the `\t` char between your elements ?

Comment: you mean add it to the list between each element? But like how? the list will treat it as a string`\t` rather than a tab. @MartinTavernier

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't test it right now. But to my knowledge, when you set file content, you can set \t as a string and it will be readed as a tab by the text editor. And then when you read the file content, you'll see \t as normal

Comment: You could use the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv` module's `DictWriter` to write tab-delimited files. To do that, you can specify the delimiter as the tab character.

```
import csv
filename = "output.txt"
a = ["rate","date","population"]
b = [4,2/3/2021,1523]
values = dict(zip(a,b))

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=a)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `\t`:

```py
a=["rate","date","population"]
b=["4","2/3/2021","1523"]

with open("data.txt","w") as outfile:
    outfile.write('\t'.join(a)+'\n')
    outfile.write('\t'.join(b))
```

Comment: true, but in case there are many fields in the header the spacing can get lost due to different tokens length. in this case, I would recommend to predefine a fixed length for each field

Comment: @jsofri In the question OP said it needs to be tab delimited. It's not necessarily for layout purposes but could be for some other automated process or file format.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your result using snippet below

```
a=["rate","date","population"]
b=['4','2/3/2021','1523']

result = '\t'.join(a) + '\n' + '\t'.join(b)

with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(result)
```

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found. I tried but it says this. since the second list is all integer I guess.

Comment: @AndrewSwainskeren it's the algorithm. You can change it to your needs. Of course, you need to use strings for concatenation. result = '\t'.join([str(element) for element in a]) +....

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

with open("data.txt", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(a)
    writer.writerow(b)
```

edit: If you want to fix your code and not use the `csv` module:

```
with open("data.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write('\t'.join(a) + '\n')
    outfile.write('\t'.join(b) + '\n')
```

The `'\t'.join(a)` is a useful function of `str` which will [**`join`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) together each value in `a` with a `\t` separating:

```
>>> '\t'.join(["if", "this", "isn't", "nice", "what", "is?"]
"if\tthis\tisn't\tnice\twhat\tis?"

>>> print(_)
if      this    isn't   nice    what    is?
```

Comment: It works. Really appreciate it! Just wondering, is there are any other ways to achieve it without using CSV module? I tried couple suggestions under this floor but all failed. @Peter Wood

Answer (score 0):

```py
a=["rate","date","population"]
b=[4,"2/3/2021",1523]

with open("data.txt","w") as outfile:
    for x in a:
        outfile.write(f'{x}\t')
    outfile.write('\n')

    for x in b:
        outfile.write(f'{x}\t')
    outfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Bravo! Thanks mate!